# Specifying Text qualifier while importing a csv file to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, delimiter

I have a comma delimited csv file, the problem is that there is a comma also within coloumns.

```
TEXT,["pn","service"]
```

`TEXT` is in one column and `["pn","service"]` the other column.

How can I use text qualifier to separate columns correctly?
[image]

Comment: If the value is `'["pn","service"]'` (not `'"pn","service"'`) then your file isn't a valid CSV file. If you the character you are using to define your delimit could/will be in a value, then you **must** use a text qualifier. Without out, then the delimiter (in your case `,`) within the text value will be treated as a delimiter; this'll be true for any CSV reader you have. If you can't change this, you'll need to use a Script task in SSIS instead and build the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: Also, if you can change the value to have a quote identifier, don't use `'"`, as that's also in your text value. If you can, I would suggest changing your delimiter. I try to use things like a pipe (`|`), as they so very rarely appear data.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with this and offer wrapping the fields with an identifier. I modified the macro below to separate by pipe instead of quote. The superuser post has more options.
Check out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291296/procedure-to-export-a-text-file-with-both-comma-and-quote-delimiters-i and https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file

Updated per @Larnu's suggestions - what I'm using to rewrap some data files prior to importing them for one off loads. Just be careful opening the CSV in excel directly... you might see values changes.

```
Sub PipeCommaExport()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Integer
   Dim RowCount As Integer

   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")

   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

   ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If

   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

      ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

         ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, "|" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & "|";

         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum,
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount

   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're posting links, you should ideally include the valid parts. Links can become dead, however, the text you have in your post will not.